# What files should I store in Azure File Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

As per the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction), I understand file storage can be used for storing logs, pictures, etc. The documentation also mentions about HTML files. Does that also mean the files such as CSS, JS, Images, etc that are part of source code should be stored in Azure File Storage, or only the files that forms data for application be stored?

Comment: It indeed depends on what service are you using in Azure. If you  just use Azure Storage , you can upload all type files to the storage.

Comment: Thank you Wayne. If I host a web application (App Service), what should be the go-to choice? Should I store source files (js,css, etc) on storage? Or it can live with application on app service?

Comment: Of course. I assume that you want to use ZIP file to deploy your Application,right? Just upload your web app file to Azure.  Also, you can use FTP, cloud sync to deploy your Web App.  For more details about how to deploy your App to Azure, refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip

Comment: Additional, I want to make clear that sometimes it depends on your Application itself. Azure hosts your Web Application on App service Plan which just seems like a VM. You should upload your Application file to Azure and run it.  Also, If your App needs to connect other resource , you can use VNet and set up VPN gateway to achieve that. **The whole file of  your app itself should be stored on Azure**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage is just... storage. Put anything you want there, really. You can store objects up to 4.7TB. It's *durable* storage (triple-replicated, non-volatile). And with different options for geo-replication.

Any object in Azure Storage can be programmatically accessed, or accessed via direct uri. Therefore, you may use Storage to contain assets for an application (images, stylesheets, whatever you choose). If you store source code, though, you'd have to build some way of downloading that source code to your target (VM, for example), and compile/run it from there. And how you do that is up to you and your approach to deploying code. (note: I'm not advocating doing that; just pointing this out).

Azure Storage isn't a file system or part of an operating system; you cannot execute code residing in Azure Storage.

And... Azure Storage is independent (as a service) to Web Apps, Virtual Machines, Functions, or any other service. You're free to access Azure Storage from any of those services, of course. And Virtual Machines utilize Azure Storage for their OS and Data disks. But... it's just a general purpose storage service.

What you choose to store there is totally up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to host a Web Application on Azure, you need to Deploy your Web app to Azure.

For your question:

> What files should I store in Azure File Storage?

First,I want to explain that the Web application is not just stored in Azure Storage Account.

For example, you can upload the ZIP file to a storage account and then use it to deploy your Web Application. **But Azure Web App service it will extract  it and deploy it to a App service Plan**. So after deploying it, you can delete it from storage account.

Second, I want to make clear that **you need upload whole source file of your Web Application to deploy**.  Azure hosts your Web Application on App service Plan which just seems like a VM. You should upload your Application file to Azure and run it.

Also, If your App needs to connect other resource , you can use VNet and set up VPN gateway to achieve that. When the Web App is running, **actually, the file is stored in the App service plan.**

Comment: I'm very confused by this answer. Why are you suggesting deploying to Web Apps through storage? Cloud Services take this approach; web apps are deployed via version control providers or ftp. And Web Apps have nothing to do with VMs (whereas Cloud Services *do* use vm's underneath, although they are stateless).

Comment: Hi,@DavidMakogon.Sorry for  my unclear answer. I didn't suggest the OP deploy web app through storage. But according to the OP's question, he may use ZIP file to deploy and be confused by that. I want to make this method clear. Also, It have nothing to do with VM, the App service plan is just looks like a VM to host web Apps.